# Playwright debug test to not close browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright

I'm using playwright and vscode, especially the "debug test" function which pops up a real browser window to run the test. When it fails the test auto closes, how can I make it not auto close so that I can modify the test and also visually see what the state of the test is?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, if I run a very simple test with `expect(true).toEqual(false)` it stops right on that line and the browser is still open. Please add details of the entension, the type of fail, or anything really.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR I think it was an extension... I uninstalled most of my extensions and now it works. Still need to double check.

Answer (score 2):

Two things I find helpful in this situation:

1. Putting a `page.pause()` immediately BEFORE the failing test will cause the debugger to break there so you can inspect the state of your app;
2. Playwright's tracing function is quite lovely and will let you see a snapshot of your app at each stage, before/after, including screen images, highlighting failing tests, and lots of other helpful data... so if you weren't expecting a test to fail, or maybe it only fails intermittently, you can use the trace to see the state at the precise moment of failure.

Comment: This is helpful answer!